# Use of hash of hashes for extracting data

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to perl and am trying to understand hashes. I've tried using a basic hash and its working. I am now trying to extract data using a hash of hashes. E.g I have a text file (input.txt) that contains some random information. How can I extract the required information using a hash of hashes structure.

### input.txt

```
hi how r you this is sample .txt. you can use it for learning hash and hash of hashes. Let say I have cell ("name") and it has value as below
cell ("name"){
  pin : A, B;
  function: A+B;
  value: 0.435;
}
```

I want to extract cell data in following format.

### Output

```
  Cell    Pin   Value
  name     A    0.435
```

I tried this:

```
  while(<$fh>)
     {
    if(/ cell \(/){$hash{cell} //=$_;}
    elsif(/ pin \(/){$hash{pin} //=$_;}

    elsif(/ value :/){$hash{value} //=$_;}
    }
    use Data::Dump;
    dd \%hash;
```

This will give only one entry in hash form. How can I get all these matches available in the input file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I edited it in que. I am not able to get it for all the matches and in table form

Comment: That code won't work. I would recommend separating this into two problems. First get the parsing working, just print what you're capturing. Then worry about putting it into a hash. Have a look at something like [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need some way to avoid the text commentary at the start of the file.  You could just skip the first line, but then random text that appears elsewhere will mess things up.  What would be better is to look for the relevant data but happily ignore any other text no matter where it appears.

Notice that the text commentary contains relevant-looking data: `cell ("name")` but there is no `{` on the end of the line.  You could use that to distinguish between the commentary and the data but that's perhaps a little too flexible.  Probably better to insist on the `{` as well as whitespace only before the `cell` declaration.

Once inside a cell, it's reasonable to insist on having no comments.  We can then just iteratively read lines and split on the `":"` until we reach the `}`.  Combined with some general advice;

1. Separate regex definition from regex use.
2. Test your matches before using the capture variables; and
3. Use 'extended mode' regexes which allow whitespace in the regex

This all gives us;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.12;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $cell_name_re =      qr/ ^ \s* cell \s* \( \s* "(\w+)" \) \s* { /x;
my $cell_data_re =      qr/ ^ \s* ([^:]+) : (\N+)  \n /x;
my $closing_curly_re =  qr/ ^ \s* }  /x;

my %data ;
while (<>) {
    next unless /$cell_name_re/ ;
    my $cell_name = $1 ;

    my %cell_hash ;
    while (<>) {
        if ( /$cell_data_re/ )  {
            $cell_hash{ $1 } = $2 ;
        }
        elsif ( /$closing_curly_re/ )  {
            $data{ $cell_name } = \%cell_hash ;
            last ;        # exit the inner loop
        }
        else {
            warn "Don't understand line $. - ignoring" ;
        }
    }
}
print Dumper( \%data );
exit 0;
```

There are two key things here - firstly, `%cell_hash` is declared inside the first loop which ensures we get a new `%cell_hash` each time through; and when we insert `%cell_hash` into the global `%data` we take a reference to it with `\`.  Running it the input data above yields;

```
    {
      'name' => {
                  'function' => ' A+B;',
                  'value' => ' 0.435;',
                  'pin ' => ' A, B;'
                }
    };
```

Comment: It helps. Still I am doing some changes

Comment: Can you tell me why we require two while loop? please. When we have cell name it is going to be assigned to $cell_name. Then how it will again check for while (<>) 2nd one.

Comment: We need two while loops because we are looking for two different things.  When outside a cell, we are looking for `cell(name)`, but once we find it and go inside a cell we are looking for `something : something` and `}`.  The program has two modes - but both modes require reading in lines to process.  So, we need two loops.  The outer loop scans looking for cells, the inner loop scans looking for data that makes up a cell.  HTH.

Comment: Coreect me if I am wrong:  let first we get the cell name. Then line after the cell name will come, it will jump to next due to !=/$cell_name_re/ condition from first while.